# Select cell in Google Sheets where cell begins with specific character

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, transpose, google-query-language

I have a range of cells B5:I5, and I need to select the cell which starts with 'R'. Tried with query, but can't the result.

Could somebody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(B5:I5; REGEXMATCH(B5:I5; "^R.+"))
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(B5:I5); "where Col1 starts with 'R'"))
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(B5:I5); "where Col1 matches '^R'"))
```

Comment: The first one helped me well. Thank you!

Maybe you also could help me with regult expression? I would like to be more specific. It should start with "R" and continue with digits, commas or "C". Like "R22", "R11,5" or "R15C".

Comment: @neznajut try: `"^R\d+.+|^R\d+,\d+.+|^R\d+C.+"`